# rails 3 devise : destroy localStorage and sessionStorage when logout?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I am using rails 3 devise and i have created some HTML 5 web storages. Now, If user click on **logout link** I want to display a confirm message. And if user click on ok button i want to set my sessionStorage value to null and now user will be logout from application.

I am inheriting devise sessions controller like:

```
 class SessionController < Devise::SessionController
   def destroy
     # code ?
   end
 end
```

And actually I can set sessionStorage value to null with javascript code:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure want to logout?")){
        sessionStorage.value = null;
    }
    return false;
  })
</script>
```

But how can i implement this code when user click on logout link? How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a Javascript action by having your logout method redirect. For example:

```
def destroy
    // ... other actions...
    redirect_to destroy_localstore_path  
end

def destroy_localstore
end
```

in your destroy_localstore.js.erb...

```
sessionStorage.value = null;
```